# How do you remove vowels from a word and print it?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that asks somebody to input a word and then the program removes any vowels in the word and prints the remaining consonant. This is what I have so far:

```
package r7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Disemvowel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a word");
        String word = stdin.next();
        String disemvowlmentWord = "";
        int len = word.length();

        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            if (c != 'a' | c != 'e' | c != 'i' | c != 'o' | c != 'u')
                disemvowlmentWord = disemvowlmentWord + c;
        }
        System.out.println(disemvowlmentWord);
    }
}
```

When I run it it just reprints whatever word I enter.

Answer (score 7):

You used a bitwise or (but every vowel isn't any other vowel), I think you wanted a logical and. This

```
if (c != 'a' | c != 'e' | c != 'i' | c != 'o' | c != 'u')
```

should be something like

```
if (c != 'a' && c != 'e' && c != 'i' && c != 'o' && c != 'u')
```

You could also use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and I would prefer a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) over creating multiple immutable `String`(s). Something like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
    if (c != 'a' && c != 'e' && c != 'i' && c != 'o' && c != 'u') {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Finally, the above test(s) could also be expressed (because of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)) like

```
if (!(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'))
```

**or** you could use a regular expression to replace vowels with an empty `String`. Something like,

```
System.out.println(word.replaceAll("[a|e|i|o|u]", ""));
```

Answer (score -3):

You are using the wrong operator. Use && instead of |